# How to get the key from OrderedDict in python

Tags: python, ordereddictionary

I have a below `OrderedDict` in python:

```
OrderedDict([(0, array([308, 186])), (2, array([431, 166]))])
```

Is there any way I can separately get the key and its value something like below:

```
print(odict[0][0])
print(odict[0][1])
print(odict[1][0])
print(odict[1][1])
```

so that I get below output

```
0
array([308, 186])
2
array([431, 166])
```

but doing above I only get:

```
308
186
431
166
```

Is there any way I can extract the keys (0, 1, 2, 3..). Please help. Thanks

Comment: you have `odict.keys()`, `odict.values()`, `odict.items()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a way to extract keys:

```
odict.keys()
```

To traverse the dict, you can:

```
for key, value in odict.items():
    print(key, value)
```

These code snippets also work on ordinary dict objects.

Answer (score 2):

You can get only keys or keys and values the following ways below, also I suppose that array instances should have been created differently, array should have elements of the same type and type of the elemnts should be declared beforehand:

[array module](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/array.html)

```
from collections import OrderedDict
from array import array

# right way to create array instance is to specifu array type:
x = OrderedDict([(0, array('I', [308, 186])), (2, array('I', [431, 166]))])  

for k in x.keys():  # print all keys
    print(k)

for k, v in x.items():  # print key and value
    print("{}___{}".format(k, v))
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get output you want through dict.items()

```
print(odict.items()[0][0])
print(odict.items()[0][1])
print(odict.items()[1][0])
print(odict.items()[1][1])
```

alternatively, you can get the dict keys() through dict.keys()

`odict.keys()` will return you `[0,2]`

Comment: ```odict.keys()```  will return ```odict_items([(0, array('I', [308, 186])), (2, array('I', [431, 166]))]) ``` whcih can be converted to list of tuples.